# Cassandra - Is there a way to update column value for entire table

Tags: cassandra, static, partitioning, insert-update

I have Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (  
    network_id int,  
    date date,  
    score float,  
    id uuid,  
    user_id int,  
    user_name  text,  
    PRIMARY KEY ((network_id, date), score, id))
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (score DESC);
```

Query which I need to satisfy is:
"Give me all users which belongs to specific network for specific day sorted by score."

The problem is when user change his name (today) and when I have to execute query for some day in past my report will show old version of the name.

Changing column user_name to STATIC doesn't work because my table should be partitioned by day.

Any ideas how to solve this?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

**Since you have denormalized user_name for faster access, If the user_name updated you have to update all the copy of that user_name.**

You need to maintain another table

```
CREATE TABLE network_by_user_id (  
    user_id int,
    network_id int,  
    date date,  
    score float,  
    id uuid,  
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, network_id, date, score, id)
);
```

So now whenever any user update their name you have to select all the record of that user from `network_by_user_id` table and for each record update user_name of base table

```
update test set user_name = 'New Name' where network_id = ? and date = ? and score = ? and id = ?
```

---

**If the number of record for a user fastly increase over time, then the cost of update `user_name` will also fastly increase over time.**

Another approach is to normalize the base table like below :

```
CREATE TABLE test (  
    network_id int,  
    date date,  
    score float,  
    id uuid,  
    user_id int,  
    PRIMARY KEY ((network_id, date), score, id)
);


CREATE TABLE users (  
    user_id int,  
    user_name  text,  
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

For each `user_id` found in the base table you can query into `users` with execute async to get the `user_name`

Learn More about [executeAsync](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/)

Comment: This approach crossed my mind, and I was wandering is better to do update of my initial table or to do join these two tables on the client side. What do you think?

Answer (score -1):

you can use SELECT command if you want to get any data from your Table

Comment: I know how to get data, problem is how to model table to update all user_names in past (multiple partitions) when same users (same id) change their names and need to be inserted, updated in table.